# outputting 2 positions from same file into script and then echo

Tags: grep, ip, echo, ping, for

I have a file which looks like this:

```
Sender Bob IP 10.1.1.1
Sender Alex IP 10.1.1.2
Sender Jim IP 10.1.1.3
```

10 lines like this in same format.
I need to echo Name and IP.
While iterating through my for loop of IPs, because i am ping testing each IP.

So far, I have been able to do this:

```
THEIP=$(cat /tmp/files/extract.txt | awk '{print $4}')
THEID=$(cat /tmp/files/extract.txt | awk '{print $2}')
extract='/tmp/files/Extracted.txt'
for i in $THEIP;
do
        echo "[INFO:]Pinging IP: $i"
        check=$(ping -w 1 $i)
                if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
                echo "[WARN:] **//sender\\** is offline"
                else
                echo "[INFO:] $i Pingable!"
                fi
done
```

This is only able to get to the ping, but I am failing to print the correlating Sender to the IP. I know I am completely ignoring `$THEID`, that is because I have not been able to figure how to implement it.

Nested for loop - it prints out IP1 + all senders, then IP2 + all senders which defeats my purpose.

My echo should be:

```
[INFO:] - Sender Bob from IP 10.1.1.1 is pingable
[INFO:] - Sender Alex from IP 10.1.1.2 is pingable
```

and so on.

Comment: Is the sender always a single word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve exactly is unclear, but something like this might work:

*Edit1: improved thanks to Glenn's comment*

*Edit2: completed the code inside the loop*

```
input="/tmp/files/extract.txt"
while read _ id _ ip; do # iterate over the lines
  echo -n "Pinging $id @ ip $ip... "
  if ping -w 1 $ip 2>&1 >/dev/null; then 
    echo OK
  else
    echo NOPE
  fi
done < "$input"
```

(bash-only version, awk might be more efficient but I'm not familiar with it)

Comment: The `read` command can read into multiple variables: `while read _ id _ ip; do echo "$id => $ip"; done` -- here, the underscore is just a variable name for junk to throw away. No need to invoke cut multiple times per line

Comment: ill clarify a bit, the Extarct file looks like this:
sender bob ipAddress 10.1.1.1
sender alex ipAddress 10.1.1.2

what im trying to achieve is this
1. ping Bob's IP - output should be "Pinging Bob @ ip 10.1.1.1"
2. ping Alex's IP - out "pinging Alex @ ip 10.1.1.2"

Comment: @dtuaev25 See my edit: is this what you have in mind? The mistake in your first attempt was that you first extracted the columns independently, but you need to keep each pair $ip $id together. In my code the file is first processed line by line, and then for each single line $ip and $id are extracted.